# how to work with threads with TSL assembly instruction in visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, win32-process, visual-c++-2012

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
ofstream myfile;
unsigned int __stdcall mythreadA(void* data) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) 
    {
    myfile << "aa";
    myfile << i;
    myfile << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    myfile.open ("report.txt");
    HANDLE myhandleA, myhandleB,myhandleC;
    myhandleA = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythreadA, 0, 0, 0);
    myhandleB = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythreadA, 0, 0, 0);
    myhandleC = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythreadA, 0, 0, 0);
    getchar();
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

if we run this program in microsoft visual studio , it creates a file "report" and then three thread try to write from number 1 to 1000000 to it . but because of concurrent run of three threads , the numbers are written to file irregular . there are ways like mutex and ... to solve this but I want only use an assembly instruction "TSL".I want to these threads run after each other and solve this with "TSL" instruction not other ways.

Answer (score 0):

In a multithreaded environment it is better to use the [interlocked ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646k06sz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and you avoid adding .asm files mainly for x64 code.